# How to play 240FPS video in AVPlayer

Tags: swift

I'm trying to play a video recorded with the camera at 240FPS, which if I export to a mp4 file, I can see the slomo part in Quicktime on a Mac.
If I try to use this same video with AVPlayer as an asset, it just plays speed up.
I've tried to check the nominalrate of the video and that gives 30, so for the app itself it's actually 30fps but I can't get to see any other segment.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961891/issue-playing-slow-mo-avasset-in-avplayer/36963210